# PHP: selecting element and changing another inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have some multidimensional arrays which I would like to enter with a `foreach`, select a specific element. Run a function with that value, and change another element inside the array with the returned value from the function. Some sample code:

Multidimensional arrays:

```
['arrayName']=>array(2)
{
    ['array2Name']=>array(1)
    {
        ['someElement']=>String(0) ""
        ['someElement']=>String(0) ""
        ['someElement']=>String(0) ""
        ['someElement']=>String(0) ""
        ['array3Name']=>array(0)
        {
            ['ElementToGet']=>String(4) "1234"
            ['ElementToChange']=>String(8) "abcdefgh"
```

I have no idea how to select the "ElementToGet". But as soon as I get it, it should be handled like this:

```
$element = (the way to select it);
$returningElement = $this->my_model->myFunction($element);
```

The returning element is supposed to replace the "ElementToChange" in the array. I have no idea how to handle this, can anyone help me?

Comment: It's nested, like so: `$array['arrayName']['array2Name']['array3Name']['ElementToGet']`. You can use that in a read or a write capacity, to get or set the elements you refer to.

Comment: ended up using alot of nested foreach loops with testing if the next was an array. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the resolution myself. A lot of nested `foreach` loops.

If anyone else have the same problem, here is my way of doing it:

```
foreach($newsletter_structure as $category_tree)
    {
        if(is_array($category_tree))
        {
            foreach($category_tree as $a)
            {
                if(is_array($a))
                {
                    foreach($a as $b)
                    {
                        if(is_array($b))
                        {
                            foreach($b as $c)
                            {
                                if(is_array($c))
                                {
                                    foreach($c as $d)
                                    {
                                        if(is_array($d))
                                        {
                                            foreach($d as $e)
                                            {
                                                $newsitem_id = $e['Id'];
                                                $newUrl = $this->setupLoggingUrl($newsitem_id, $newsletter_id);
                                                $e['URL'] = $newUrl;
```

Used the `if(is_array())` in order to avoid any possible errors.